# How to Mock object.getMap().get("String_Key_to_return_Object")

Tags: java, spring, maven, mockito, junit4

How can I Mock This kind Of situation

```
   ObjectOfBeanClass.getMapObject().get("String_Key_To_Return_Object")
```

I try the following Ways :

> 1) 
>   when(ObjectOfBeanClass.getMapObject().get("String_Key_To_Return_Object")).thenReturn(Object);
>
> In this Case, it throws an exception that getMapObject() Should return
>   a Map_Object
>
> 2)
>   doReturn(Object).when(ObjectOfBeanClass.getMapObject()).thenReturn(Object);
>
> in this case, it shows following error
>   org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException: 
>   Unfinished stubbing detected here:

Answer (score 3):

You mock the map as a whole and the call in two steps.

```
Map<String> map = mock(Map.class);
when(map.get(yourString)).thenReturn(object);
when(objectOfBeanClass.getMap()).thenReturn(map);
```

Or, if `objectOfBeanClass` is your test subject, call

```
objectOfBeanClass.setMap(map);
```

As chrylis points out, you may as well create an actual `Map` instance instead of mocking it:

```
Map<String> map = Collections.singletonMap("String_Key", object);
when(objectOfBeanClass.getMap()).thenReturn(map);
```

which is fine as long as you don't want to use the map for `verify()` or something like that.

Comment: It's almost never worth mocking an interface like `Map`. Just use `Collections.singletonMap` or a real `HashMap`.

Comment: @chrylis That's true, although you might want to use the map for verification which is only possible on a mock. I edited the answer.

Comment: Generally speaking, though, if the information in the map is needed, it will have some sort of reflection in the rest of what happens (e.g., it'll be transferred to the outgoing method call on the service being mocked or available via a getter on the class under test). If it has no visible effect on behavior, it probably just needs to go away entirely.